# TypeScript Generics: 'type is not assignable to type T'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have made a factory that will create instances of certain classes. I want to use generics to ensure that all of the objects returned are from sub-classes that extend an abstract classes.

I thought that the logic of the `createInstance` method shown below could be described as 'createInstance() will return a type `T` that is constrained to be a class that extends Animal.

As you can see, Lion extends Animal, but I still get the compiler warning `type Lion is not assignable to type T`.

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract makeSound(): void;
}

class Bear extends Animal {
    public makeSound() {
        console.log('growl');
    }
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    public makeSound() {
        console.log('roar');
    }
}

function createInstance<T extends Animal>(type: string): T {
    switch(type) {
        case 'bear':
            return new Bear(); // 'type Bear is not assignable to type T'
        case 'lion':
            return new Lion(); // 'type Lion is not assignable to type T'
    }
}

createInstance().makeSound();
```

I have read at the end of the [TypeScript Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) docs that:

> When creating factories in TypeScript using generics, it is necessary
>   to refer to class types by their constructor functions. For example,
>
> ```
> function create<T>(c: {new(): T; }): T {
>     return new c();
> }
> ```

but I don't really want to have to pass in the class constructor into the function if possible and would like to understand why I'm getting the `not assignable to type T` message in the first place.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If your function always returns a `Lion` it's result type is not really generic. You could for example write `create<Tiger>()` and your function would still return a `Lion`. A true generic function would return a value that honors the generic parameter.

You could pass the constructor as an argument, as you discovered:

```
function create<T>(c: {new(): T; }): T {
    return new c();
}
```

Or you could make your function not generic, and have it return an `Animal` or a `Lion`. You could have more overloads, if you have logic based on argument values that determine the return type:

```
// Public signatures, we tie function parameter values to return value for specific types
function createInstance(type: "Lion"): Lion 
function createInstance(type: "Tiger"): Tiger 
// Private signature, not visible from outside
function createInstance(type: "Lion" | "Tiger"): Animal {
    if(type === "Lion") {
        return new Lion();
    }
    else if(type === "Tiger") {
        return new Tiger(); 
    }
}
let tiger = createInstance("Tiger"); // will be typed as Tiger
let lion = createInstance("Lion");// will be typed as Lion
let err = createInstance("Lama");// will be an error since the function does not know how to create a Lama
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Bad example on my part. I meant it to be possible for there to be a choice of classes to return depending on a switch. Let me change the example.

Comment: `A true generic function would return a value that honors the generic parameter`. So now that I have changed my example and have 2 options in the `createInstance()` method, is my class not generic in that it always needs to return a class that extends Animal? I do not want it to simply return an Animal, because I may want to use other sub-class specific methods and properties. Instead I just want to know that the returned value *is* an Animal, so that I can be sure that I it has a `makeSound()` method, but I want that that actual subclass instance.

Comment: @Joe It's still not generic because it does not work for any `T` only a limited number of  classes derived from `Animal`. You should consider the overload option, it's exactly what you are looking for, It returns a specific type of animal based on parameter value.

Comment: Thanks Titian. That's very helpful